# Pinterest like grid in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list of containers which all have the same width and different heights. I want to fill the screen with them. From top left, to top right, to below, etc.

Similar thing can be seen in Pinterest and also Google Keep. Notice that the screen might resize so I don't know the number of columns.

I have tried `flutter_staggered_grid_view`. The most similar thing I could find was the Masonry grid. But it changed the width of the containers.

Comment: can you show us your Masonry Grid code? it should be work as your description by adding crossAxisCount parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example for pinterest like grid in Flutter. Width of images doesn't change. I hope that helps.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double itemwidth = 250;
    double crossAxisCount = w / (itemwidth);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: newMethod(),
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: MasonryGridView.count(
                      itemCount: 50,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                      crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount.toInt(),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        int randomHeight = Random().nextInt(6);
                        return UnconstrainedBox(
                            child: Container(
                                width: itemwidth,
                                height: (randomHeight % 5 + 2) * 100,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        image: NetworkImage(
                                            "https://picsum.photos/100/${(randomHeight % 5 + 2) * 100}")))));
                      }))
            ])));
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can check the Pinterest website to see the layout. I believe in here you're setting the number of columns. Which should not be given.

Comment: How can we make the spacing between the containers static? So that the whole columns stay at the center and the spacing added to the margin of the page instead of between the containers. You can also check the pinterest website to get the idea.

Comment: figured it out. need to wrap column with container with this width: `w - (w % itemWidth)`

Comment: there are minor differences as well. 
- the scroll bar is not to the top right (if we have the border in the edge)
- some of the containers might not be added to the top but a little down. so the height of first row doesn't start from the same position.

Comment: that first row problem was actually from me. fixed.

Comment: another problem: the scrollbar jumps. not stable.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this extension in your project:

```
extension Responsive on BuildContext {
  T responsive<T>(
    T defaultVal, {
    T? sm,
    T? md,
    T? lg,
    T? xl,
  }) {
    final wd = MediaQuery.of(this).size.width;
    return wd >= 1280
        ? (xl ?? lg ?? md ?? sm ?? defaultVal)
        : wd >= 1024
            ? (lg ?? md ?? sm ?? defaultVal)
            : wd >= 768
                ? (md ?? sm ?? defaultVal)
                : wd >= 640
                    ? (sm ?? defaultVal)
                    : defaultVal;
  }
}
```

this extension will listen to changes of screen width and return a matched value, so your gridView would be something like this:

```
GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: context.responsive(2, sm: 2, md: 3, lg: 4, xl: 6),
            children: items
                .map(
                  (final e) => Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Text(e),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
```

so gridView crossAxisCount will increase as long as the screen width goes larger.

Comment: this doesn't meet the requirement. changes both the width and height of my containers.

Comment: use staggered grid view instead of my mentioned simple grid view, the hint here is the responsive extension, you need to implement it with your wished grid view.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use sliverGrid ?

it will be something like this :

```
class MySliverGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;
  final List<Widget> widgets;
  const MySliverGrid({Key? key, required this.width, required this.widgets})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverGrid(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(widgets),
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ~/ width)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is getting width as the input. i don't have it.

Comment: didn't you said "list of containers which all have the same width and different heights" , you just have to create a blank screen and put one of the item in list in the screen then measure it, ( you don't need width , you only need a number of item you want to put in on row ) . in my code when you get the number o item you want to put in horizontally , change crossAxisCount: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ~/ width)

Comment: I have the width of each container yes. They are already set in the containers. I got an error with this btw: `A RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverGrid.`

Comment: tried. doesn't meet any of the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a Pinterest-like grid layout with containers of the same width but different heights, you can use the `flutter_staggered_grid_view` package along with `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount`. This combination allows you to create a responsive staggered grid that adjusts the number of columns based on the available screen width.

```
class PinterestGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  PinterestGrid({super.key});

  //Create a list of container heights (you can replace this with your actual data):
  final List<double> containerHeights = [150, 250, 200, 180, 220, 190];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Pinterest Like Grid'),
      ),
      body: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        crossAxisCount: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 600 ? 3 : 2,
        itemCount: containerHeights.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: containerHeights[index],
            child: Center(
              child: Text('$index'),
            ),
          );
        },
        staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => const StaggeredTile.fit(1),
        mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add this two

```
import 'package:staggered_grid_view_flutter/widgets/staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'package:staggered_grid_view_flutter/widgets/staggered_tile.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this: (its in just one file due simplicity, but if it works fine for ya you may use the block of code you may need)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Assuming this is your data model class with `title` and `height` properties
class Item {
  final String title;
  final double height;

  Item(this.title, this.height);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Sample list of Items
    final List<Item> items = [
      Item('Item 1', 100.0),
      Item('Item 2', 200.0),
      Item('Item 3', 150.0),
      // Add more items here
    ];

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        ),
        body: GridView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          // Calculates the number of columns based on the screen width
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: calculateColumns(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
            mainAxisSpacing: 10,  // Adjust as needed
            crossAxisSpacing: 10,  // Adjust as needed
          ),
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              height: items[index].height,
              child: Card(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Item ${items[index].title}'),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  int calculateColumns(double screenWidth) {
    int columns = (screenWidth ~/ 150);  // Adjust the column width as needed
    return columns > 0 ? columns : 1;
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```